# not displaying 1st marker in for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markers

I insert only two `items` just to see how the `xml` looks like.The loop displays in every `item` the `image` : '1.gif' but NOT in the first item.In the first one displays the default marker.
Any ideas how i'm gonna have in the 1st item the image-marker(1.gif)?
Here's a link of the code : **http://metartestmobile.netau.net/folder6/pirkagia.php**
***EDITED***

```
var map;
        var infowindow;
            function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.822590,24.653320);
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 6,
              center: myLatlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var pirkagia1  = 'pirkagia/1.gif';
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            <?php foreach ( $item_array as $item ) : ?>

                            if ( parseFloat ( '<?php echo $item["fire"] ?>') == 1 ) {
                                var contentString = '<?php echo $item['title']; ?>';                
                                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $item['glat'] ?>,<?php echo $item['glon'] ?>);               
                                var marker1 = createMarker1( contentString,latlng,pirkagia1 );
                            }
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            function createMarker1( contentString,latlng,pirkagia1 ) {
                            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            map: map,
                            icon: pirkagia1
                            });
                        google.maps.event.addListener( marker1, "click", function() {
                        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
                            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: contentString
                            });
                            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
                        });
                        return marker1;
                        }
}
```

and a sample odf the `xml` file

```
    <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>
Real time weather in Greece
    </title>
    <link>http://www.123.gr/</link>
    <image>
    <url>
    http://www.123.gr/templates/123/images/123.gif
    </url>
    <title>metar.gr</title>
    <link>http://www.123.gr/</link>
    </image>
    <description>
    Ο καιρός σε πραγματικό χρόνο | Real time weather in Greece | Ενημέρωση Fri, 02 May 2014 15:07:05 +0300
    </description>
    <language>el</language>
    <pubDate>Fri, 02 May 2014 15:07:05 +0300</pubDate>
    <copyright>123.gr</copyright>
    <managingEditor>kondilis@123.gr</managingEditor>
    <webMaster>admin@123.gr</webMaster>
    <item>
    <title>Alexan</title>
    <fire>1</fire>
    <glat>39.659859</glat>
    <glon>20.857415</glon>
    </item>
    <item>
    <title>Nea Medounia</title>
    <fire>1</fire>
    <glat>40.24360843967902</glat>
    <glon>23.276864290237427</glon>
    </item>
    </channel>
```

Comment: Get us a link to this map so we can see the entire output.  Better yet if you can create a jsfiddle with the rendered page results we can adjust things and point out improvements.

Comment: @Frank Tubor. I have just edit the question.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that it appears that you are overlapping lat and long on your markers.  When I first clicked one, I got a value (three letter word) on the click on the other 'pin' I got something, but when i clicked back it showed something different...What I suggest is slightly altering your lat and long so if there hard overlap it moves one a fractional lat/long coord.

Comment: Your icons aren't defined until after the first marker is added to the map, so you get the default icon for the first one.